# UiPath: get content of text file linked from web page

Tags: google-chrome, uipath

I am using UiPath Community Edition.

There is a link in a web page, that brings to a text file (.txt). If I click on the link, it opens in a new tab. This is the HTML code:

```
<a name="URL$2" id="URL$2" ptlinktgt="pt_new" tabindex="43"
    onfocus="doFocus_win0(this,false,true);" href="https://www.test/report123.txt"
    onclick="window.open('https://www.test/report123.txt','',''); return false;"
    class="HYPERLINK">
report123.txt
</a>
```

I would like to read the content of the text file into a variable.
How should I do that?

Comment: Does this open text file in new tab or download to system?

Comment: If I click the link, it will open the file in the new tab. My goal is to get the content in a variable; downloading it into a file would also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [Web Recorder](https://docs.uipath.com/studio/docs/example-of-automatic-recording-with-web) and then [Output or Screen Scraping Methods](https://docs.uipath.com/studio/v2016.2/docs/output-or-screen-scraping-methods)?